# How to add $sql->debugDumpParams() to $sql->execute

Tags: mysql

How do I run the $sql->debugDumpParams() every time the script calls $sql->execute()

Do I need to extend the class?

Comment: Is this a [tag:php] related question?

Comment: Yes it is sorry. Php and Pdo